# How to use pre-generated Tiles

Tags: qgis, geoserver, tiles

i have just created Tiles with Qtiles on Qgis, but how can put these folders (tile .png) on GeoServer or Mapserver?

I am trying to put the folder in  C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.0\data_dir\gwc but i can't see it on GeoServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need geoserver or mapserver to serve the tiles. Put them on a webserver and access them with OpenLayers.Layer.GeoWebCache

Comment: -1 Sorry, don't take it personally but i had to downvote you because the OP specifically asked about premade tiles and Geoserver

Comment: I have not a server, can i see them in localhost? if yes where i should put them? thank you!

Comment: Put them in a folder under www in the geoserver data dir and you can se them under localhost.

Comment: @nickves - Well technically hes asked if it was possible to put it in Geoserver, under its GWC. You can probably put it in GWC by editing the GWC serverices configuration (All info on extent, srs etc. should be filled out manually), but it would then be the GWC that the direct request would go to, not Geoserver. I dont think that it is possible to make Geoserver consider this a service that it will provide, since there is no store/layer configuration to fall back upon on request and for getcapabilites generation. Therefor i suggesteded the simple functional solution...